# How to get instance variables in Python?

Tags: python, methods, instance-variables

Is there a built-in method in Python to get an array of all a class' instance variables? For example, if I have this code:

```
class hi:
  def __init__(self):
    self.ii = "foo"
    self.kk = "bar"
```

Is there a way for me to do this:

```
>>> mystery_method(hi)
["ii", "kk"]
```

Edit: I originally had asked for class variables erroneously.

Comment: Your example shows "instance variables".  Class variables are another thing.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Every object has a `__dict__` variable containing all the variables and its values in it.

Try this

```
>>> hi_obj = hi()
>>> hi_obj.__dict__.keys()
```

Output

```
dict_keys(['ii', 'kk'])
```

Comment: FWIW, the inspect module gives you a more reliable method than relying on __dict__, which not all instances have.

Comment: What kind of an instance does not have __dict__?  I've never encountered one.

Comment: Certain built-in types, such as int.  Try saying "x = 5" and then "x.__dict__" and you'll get an AttributeError

Comment: Also, anything that uses __slots__.

Comment: Why would you want to try and get the class instance variables of an int? It's not even a class (although I could be wrong on that).

Comment: Also re.MatchObjects ( no `__dict__`s )

Comment: @MartinSherburn Because someone may want to get instances' variables within knowing in advance what types will be encountered.

Comment: What does the example output look like for this code?

Comment: Also numpy ndarrays return an AttributeError when you try to access their attributes using ```__dict__```

Answer (score 131):

Use [vars()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

vars(Foo()) #==> {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
vars(Foo()).keys() #==> ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: +1  I personally think this syntax is cleaner than using __dict__, since attributes with double underscores are supposed to be "private" in Python syntax.

Comment: @Martin: `__method` is private, `__method__` is a special method, not necessarily private; I would like to say the special methods define an object's capabilites rather than methods.

Comment: `__method__` is quite ugly, and I think they have been named that way to try and deter people away from using them unless absolutely necessary. In this case we have the alternative vars().

Comment: in my case I tried calling vars(ObjName) and it returns a dict_proxy with a dictionary whose keys are the methods of the given class/object, but no sign of __init__ elements. Any guesses why?

Comment: Double Underscore Variables `__str__`, `__method__` are for the language itself normally. What happens when you `str(something)`?

Answer (score 19):

You normally can't get instance attributes given just a class, at least not without instantiating the class. You can get instance attributes given an instance, though, or class attributes given a class. See the 'inspect' module. You can't get a list of instance attributes because instances really can have anything as attribute, and -- as in your example -- the normal way to create them is to just assign to them in the __init__ method.

An exception is if your class uses slots, which is a fixed list of attributes that the class allows instances to have. Slots are explained in http://www.python.org/2.2.3/descrintro.html, but there are various pitfalls with slots; they affect memory layout, so multiple inheritance may be problematic, and inheritance in general has to take slots into account, too.

Comment: Downvoting because "you can't get a list of instance attributes" is simply wrong: both vars() and __dict__ give you exactly that.

Comment: I assume he meant "you can't get a list of all possible instance attributes".  For example, I often use lazy generation and the @property decorator to add an instance variable the first time it's requested.  Using __dict__ would tell you about this variable once it existed but not beforehand.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and please notice what I actually said: you can't get a list of instance attributes *given just a class*, which is what the code accompanying the question tries to do.

Comment: @Carl: Please educate yourself before writing false comments and downvoting based your lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 16):

You can also test if an object has a specific variable with:

```
>>> hi_obj = hi()
>>> hasattr(hi_obj, "some attribute")
False
>>> hasattr(hi_obj, "ii")
True
>>> hasattr(hi_obj, "kk")
True
```

Answer (score 16):

Both the Vars() and dict methods will work for the example the OP posted, but they won't work for "loosely" defined objects like:

```
class foo:
  a = 'foo'
  b = 'bar'
```

To print all non-callable attributes, you can use the following function:

```
def printVars(object):
    for i in [v for v in dir(object) if not callable(getattr(object,v))]:
        print '\n%s:' % i
        exec('print object.%s\n\n') % i
```

Comment: `exec('print object.%s\n\n') % i` should be written as `print getattr(object, i)`

Answer (score 9):

Your example shows "instance variables",  not really class variables.

Look in `hi_obj.__class__.__dict__.items()` for the class variables, along with other other class members like member functions and the containing module.

```
class Hi( object ):
    class_var = ( 23, 'skidoo' ) # class variable
    def __init__( self ):
        self.ii = "foo" # instance variable
        self.jj = "bar"
```

Class variables are shared by all instances of the class.

Comment: ```list(filter(None,[ i[0] if not i[0].startswith('_') else None for i in h.__class__.__dict__.items()]))``` essentially

Answer (score 6):

Suggest

```
>>> print vars.__doc__
vars([object]) -> dictionary

Without arguments, equivalent to locals().
With an argument, equivalent to object.__dict__.
```

In otherwords, it essentially just wraps __dict__

Answer (score 5):

Although not directly an answer to the OP question, there is a pretty sweet way of finding out what variables are in scope in a function. take a look at this code:

```
>>> def f(x, y):
    z = x**2 + y**2
    sqrt_z = z**.5
    return sqrt_z

>>> f.func_code.co_varnames
('x', 'y', 'z', 'sqrt_z')
>>>
```

The func_code attribute has all kinds of interesting things in it. It allows you todo some cool stuff. Here is an example of how I have have used this:

```
def exec_command(self, cmd, msg, sig):

    def message(msg):
        a = self.link.process(self.link.recieved_message(msg))
        self.exec_command(*a)

    def error(msg):
        self.printer.printInfo(msg)

    def set_usrlist(msg):
        self.client.connected_users = msg

    def chatmessage(msg):
        self.printer.printInfo(msg)

    if not locals().has_key(cmd): return
    cmd = locals()[cmd]

    try:
        if 'sig' in cmd.func_code.co_varnames and \
                       'msg' in cmd.func_code.co_varnames: 
            cmd(msg, sig)
        elif 'msg' in cmd.func_code.co_varnames: 
            cmd(msg)
        else:
            cmd()
    except Exception, e:
        print '\n-----------ERROR-----------'
        print 'error: ', e
        print 'Error proccessing: ', cmd.__name__
        print 'Message: ', msg
        print 'Sig: ', sig
        print '-----------ERROR-----------\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you want to filter the list based on public/private vars.  E.g.

```
def pub_vars(self):
    """Gives the variable names of our instance we want to expose
    """
    return [k for k in vars(self) if not k.startswith('_')]
```

Answer (score 2):

built on dmark's answer to get the following, which is useful if you want the equiv of sprintf and hopefully will help someone...

```
def sprint(object):
    result = ''
    for i in [v for v in dir(object) if not callable(getattr(object, v)) and v[0] != '_']:
        result += '\n%s:' % i + str(getattr(object, i, ''))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first, **examine the class**, next, **examine the bytecode for functions**, then, **copy the bytecode**, and finally, **use the `__code__.co_varnames`**. **This is tricky** because **some classes create their methods using constructors like those in the `types` module**. I will provide code for it on [GitHub](https://github.com/g7a20/class-inst-vars).

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer of Ethan Joffe

```
def print_inspect(obj):
  print(f"{type(obj)}\n")
  var_names = [attr for attr in dir(obj) if not callable(getattr(obj, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
  for v in var_names: 
    print(f"\tself.{v} = {getattr(obj, v)}\n")
```