# Get list of attributes in class

Tags: python

How would I get  a list of attributes in a class? For example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,**kw):
        for k,v in kw.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
x = Test(value="hello",valueTwo="world")
print(dir(x))
```

I've done that and it seems to print the keys but, it also prints extra stuff like:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__','value','valueTwo']
```

is there another way to do this so it just gets the keys/values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Get Instance Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109087/python-get-instance-variables)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `x.__dict__`:

```
>>> x.__dict__
{'value': 'hello', 'valueTwo': 'world'}

>>> [ v for k,v in x.__dict__.items() if '__' not in k and 'object at' not in k ]
```

Comment: Thank you I used x.__dict__.keys() to just get the keys, thanks for this method I didn't know I could do that.

Comment: I think we will also have other `__abc__` keys in the result of `__dict__`. Added some filter to your answer.

Comment: not working for dataclasses