# Property decorator does not add the attribute to __dict__

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, python-decorators

I would like to retrieve all the attributes of a given instance. [I know I could use `__dict__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620631/get-list-of-attributes-in-class), but it's not working in my case, because I'm declaring some attributes using the `@property` decorator.

```
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ""
        self._b = ""

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value

    def f(self):
         print "hello"
```

These are the results I get:

```
>>> A().__dict__
{'a': '', '_b': ''}
>>> dir(A())
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', '_b', 'a', 'b', 'f']
```

But the result I want is the following one:

```
>>> get_all_the_attributes(A())
{'a': '', '_b': '', 'b': ''}
```

Or:

```
>>> get_all_the_attributes(A())
['a', '_b', 'b']
```

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: @BhargavRao This would add the `f` method too

Comment: Oh yeah. i had forgotten bout that!

Comment: Why do you want to see `b` listed in `instance.__dict__`? There is *no such attribute*, you have a property instead.

Comment: Related: [list @property decorated methods in a python class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27503965)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, maybe the title is a bit missleading. I don't want `b` especially in `__dict__`, but I'd rather want a way to list all the attributes of my instance, including those for which I used the `@property` decorator.

Comment: @julienc: then see the other question, and append the keys of `__dict__` to that to get that list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed, I think this is exactly what I need! Sorry for the duplicate post then, I did not find the original one when I looked for an answer.

Comment: Note that, unless you *particularly* need to access the "private" attribute (e.g. if `None` was an acceptable starting default but you wouldn't want a user to set it), you should assign to `b` rather than `_b` in `__init__`; this ensures that all access is managed correctly.

Comment: Not a problem, now your question can help future users find that post a little bit better. :-)