# Python class instances introspection

Tags: python, oop, instance, introspection

From the introspection perspective is there a way to get a class instances variables without creating an instance. When an instance is created it is easy:

```
class Super:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Sub(Super):
    pass

a = Super("Nice_Name")

print(a.__dict__.keys())
```

But I want to get that information without creating an instance, just to introspect. Is there way to do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109087/how-to-get-instance-variables-in-python

Comment: What would their values be if they had no instance?

Comment: The problem is that class instances don't have any attributes at all until they are assigned; the class does not "declare" them. `__init__` simply assigns values to attributes created on the fly after the instance is first created. Essentially, you are asking to simulate the execution of `__init__`.

Comment: More so the `__init__` function may not even create a deterministic set of properties. It could depend on arguments, global state, or even be something absurd such as `setattr(self, str(random.random()), "derp")`

Comment: OK, but lets say if I will try to use Sub class and doesn't assign any value to it. It will give me error. As Sub "knows" that it needs "name". The same with Super class. So that means that somehow that information is there. So if subclass knows where to look for instance variables. Can't I do that? I hope that I am not mixing something here as I am quite new to Python.

Comment: @Vy.Iv: Can you post an example of code where that error happens?

Comment: @Vy.Iv It won't give you an error.

Comment: So, lets say a = Sub() and error: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). As I understand from comments and Natecat answer, when I don't add anything it raises errror as it tries to create instance and it can see that intance variable is missing. Before I do that it is not there. Is that the case?

Comment: @Vy.Iv: That error isn't related to instance variables - it's related to the arguments to the constructor function (`__init__`). And those you could indeed find out with introspection, but they're not what you're after.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: It is a bit related, atleast it will solve my problem, I think. Just to be sure that I understand it. Those arguments using constructor function will be hooked to the instance variable that we can't introspect without instance creation, but we can inspect arguments without instance creation?

Comment: @Vy.Iv: The arguments have nothing to with instance variables. They're just arguments to the function. It's free to do whatever it wants with them.

Comment: @Vy.Iv:  You're suffering from a misconception, that "`Sub` 'knows' that it needs `name`.".  It doesn't, as you can see by looking at it.  When you call _any_ instance method, including the invisible call to `__init__`, Python searches the instance for that method.  If the method isn't found (it isn't, because `Sub` doesn't have / "know about" `__init__`), Python searches related classes in Method Resolution Order until it finds the method or gives up.  The next class is `Super`, which _does_ have an `__init__`.  Python runs `Super`'s `__init__`, assigning the new `Sub` instance to `self`.

Comment: @Vy.Iv:  Assuming you come from some other OOP language...  `__init__` is an _initializer_, not a constructor.  (The constructor is `__new__` --- you will rarely if ever fiddle with it.)  By the time the initializer runs, the instance of `Sub` has already been constructed (containing only Python-provided fields like `__class__` and `__dict__`).  That's how there is an instance of _anything_ to assign to the `self` parameter of `WhicheverClass.__init__`.  The rest of the `__init__` parameters are assigned using the arguments from your (implicit) call to the initializer: `sub = Sub("Whatever")`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot, because python is not a [statically typed language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517670/1357527), so before an object is instantiated, that object has no type. For example, imagine a class like this:

```
class A:
def __init__(self):
    self.a = "a"

def change_type(self):
    self.a = 1
```

What would the type of `self.a` be before an object is instantiated? If you need introspection, you cannot use python.

Comment: Simply because this is not an answer or is a link-only answer. put this as comment. Just look at the other persons comments to the question: they are longer and more constructive. SO rules, sorry

Comment: @Apero I disagree. His question is wholly answered by this, and the link is to clarify what a statically typed language IS, and by it self doesn't answer his question.

Comment: Indeed, so this should be a comment, not an answer ;-)

Comment: @Apero I was talking about the link, not the answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with statically typing or not.  Perl and Javascript and ruby all have "classes".  Speaking of Perl, - perl used to do it this python way (early perl 5).  Then it added the class keyword.  It's still dynamic behind the scenes, but it creates a template that both enforces how the class is built, and that can be introspected...  Perl 6 ups it a notch.

Comment: @GerardONeill Statically typed languages aren't a monolithic category, they sometimes do things that don't quite fit into that paradigm. The important part here is the types are assigned at runtime, which is the defining feature of a statically typed languages.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some research into this and there appear to be a few scenarios where you *can* do this, however no perfect solution:

1. If you define instance variables using `@property` decorators, then it will show up when doing `dir(class_type)`
2. Similarly, you can define the allowed list of instance attributes using `__slots__` magic var, and then just do `class_type.__slots__` to get your instance vars.
3. A bit more hacky, but you can read the source code of the class, and then look for any references to `self.varname = expression`. This of course assumes `self` will is always how the class instance is referenced, and would fail in scenarios like inner classes or `self` being reassigned to another varname. Also wouldn't pick up things like `setattr(self, varname, expression)`, which you'd need other logic to detect.
4. Probably more robust than option #3, you could use the `ast` module and use that to parse the class source code. Then do some searching to find expressions that might write attributes to the class `self`.

Check out this example:

```py
import dill, re

class Test:
    __slots__ = ["x","y","z"]
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 1
        self.z = 2
    @property
    def q(self):
        return self.x

# this grabs those defined using __slots__ or @property
print(dir(Test))

# this looks at class source
# may need to play around with the regex more...
s = dill.source.getsource(Test)
var_finder = re.compile("self\.([^\W]+)\s*\=")
print(set(var_finder.findall(s)))
```

I personally think adding `__slots__` on your class is the best approach. For sphinx documentation, which was my use case, that seems to be the best way to get `autosummary` directive to pick up those instance variables.