# How to print dictionary when value is an object (Python)

Tags: python, object, dictionary, printing, mapping

myDict = {name1: object1, name2: object2, etc....}

*The objects look like this:

```
Color: Blue, Flies: True, etc...
```

EDIT: included above dictionary so you can see what I'm working with.

While researching how to print the preceding dictionary in a nice, readable fashion, I tried the following code:

```
for key in myDict:
        print (key)
        for value in myDict[key]:
            print (value, ":", myDict[key][value])
```

This would work, HOWEVER, my "value"'s are all OBJECTS and it says that it can't iterate (which makes sense).  I just want to know how to make it work the way it would if the value was a list or something that was iterable.

My desired output format is something like this:

```
Item1:              --> Key (it's the name of the object)
Color: Blue         --> Value (this is object[0])
Flies: True         --> Value (this is object[1])
etc....
```

Thanks!

Comment: What "following dictionary" ?

Comment: **Most** objects have `.__dict__` dictionary in them. In your case: you would just replace `myDict[key]` with `myDict[key].__dict__`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Just made an edit

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Thanks.  I knew there was the  .__dict__ I just wasn't quite sure how to use it.  I'll try it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get instance variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109087/how-to-get-instance-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You could just catch the `TypeError` that occurs when trying to iterate a noniterable (might want to make exceptions for strings though).

```
try:
    for value in myDict[key]:
        print (value, ":", myDict[key][value])
except TypeError:
   print value
```