# Looping through an object's (class instance) properties in python and printing them

Tags: python, oop, properties

In python, how can an object's properties be accessed without explicitly calling them? And print those properties?

Ex:

```
class MyClass:
     def __init__(self):
     self.prop1 = None
     self.prop2 = 10

     def print_properties(self):
     # Print the property name and value

example_a = MyClass()
example_a.print_properties()
```

Desired output:

```
prop1: None
prop2: 10
```

Different from: [using object.**dict**.keys()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109087/how-to-get-instance-variables-in-python/) as it was pointed out that accessing the `private` `__dict__` methods is not advised. Linked posted is 2008 answer and doesn't define how to iterate through the object.

Comment: Iterating is then the same as iterating through a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not using private `__dict__`, 
you have python built-in function called `vars()`

```
def print_properties(self):
    for prop, value in vars(self).items():
        print(prop, ":", value) # or use format
```

Explantion of vars, from pythom offical docs:

> Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any
>   other object with a `__dict__` attribute.
>
> Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable `__dict__`
>   attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their
>   `__dict__` attributes (for example, new-style classes use a dictproxy to prevent direct dictionary updates).
>
> Without an argument, `vars()` acts like `locals()`. Note, the locals
>   dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals
>   dictionary are ignored.

Comment: I'll throw that in there!

Comment: Made an edit, is it answering your question ?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: You are right we forgot the iteration on the dict, `vars()` returns dict of key, value of all the properties of the class. So now we are using `items()` to iterate over them.

Answer (score 2):

I found for a basic object, the following internal function accomplishes the task:

```
def print_properties(self):
    for attr in self.__dict__:
        print(attr, ': ', self.__dict__[attr])
```

All together:

```
>>class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = None
        self.prop2 = 10
    def print_properties(self):
        for attr in vars(self):
             print(attr, ': ', vars(self)[attr])

>>example_a = MyClass()
>>example_a.print_properties()
prop1 :  None
prop2 :  10

>>example_a.prop1 = 'Bananas'
>>example_a.print_properties()
prop1 :  Bananas
prop2 :  10
```