# Python how to print attributes for itertools.permutations

Tags: python, attributes, python-itertools

I am new to Python and am trying out `itertools`:

```
import itertools as it
obj = it.permutations(range(4))
print(obj)
for perm in obj:
    print( perm )
```

**My Question: How do I view/print all the permutations in `obj` *directly* without using a `for` loop?**

**What I Tried:**
I tried using `__dict__` and `vars` as suggested in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109087/how-to-get-instance-variables-in-python) but both do not work (former does not seem to exist for the object while latter generated 'TypeError: 'itertools.permutations' object is not callable').

Please pardon if my question is rather noobish - this attributes issue appears complicated and most of what is written in [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python/610923#610923) flew over my head.

Comment: you cast it to list; `list(it.permutations(range(4)))`

Comment: BUT, why do you need `itertools` ?

Comment: Thanks @Ev.Kounis! I've been trying so many different things in vain for the last few hours! Would you like to post it as a solution so that I can accept it?

Comment: @FrankAK The lecturer in my course just used it as part of his solution to a different problem and I was just poking around out of curiousity...

Comment: Many things in 3.6 return generators (map, zip, itertools.*) - they all need to be iterated to be consumed. If you stuff them inside a `list(gener)` it will internally iterate all of them and return a list containting each result in it. you can also stuff / evaluate them in list/set/dict comprehensions wich will also iterate over the generator-results.

Comment: Hi @PatrickArtner, is there a rule-of-thumb to know what is returned by various built-in methods? I read the help() for `permutations` - nowhere does it say a `generator` is returned. Hope you don't mind enlightening further...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertool-functions : First sentence: `The following module functions all construct and return iterators.` - there is a difference between "iterables" "sequences" and "generators"(which I think of as returning a finite length iterable by means of giving you an iterator) that I happen to grapple with. Good post: [what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration).

Comment: @PatrickArtner: will read up on those concepts. And thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast your `obj` to a `list`:

```
print(list(obj))
```

This will give you the following output:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2), (0, 2, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3, 1), (0, 3, 1, 2), (0, 3, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 3, 2), (1, 2, 0, 3), (1, 2, 3, 0), (1, 3, 0, 2), (1, 3, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1, 3), (2, 0, 3, 1), (2, 1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 3, 0), (2, 3, 0, 1), (2, 3, 1, 0), (3, 0, 1, 2), (3, 0, 2, 1), (3, 1, 0, 2), (3, 1, 2, 0), (3, 2, 0, 1), (3, 2, 1, 0)]
```

That's the direct answer to your question. Another good thing to figure out is whether you really need what you are asking for.

You see, there is a reason why [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) returns a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3.1/glossary.html#term-generator). If you ain't familiar with that pattern, I'd strongly suggest reading about it. To make a long story short, generally you don't wanna cast such things to a `list` unless you really need it to be a `list` (e.g. you want to access items directly by index). In your case where you only need to print permutations there is *absolutely* nothing wrong with using `for` loop.

Here is one-liner to print one permutation per line:

```
print('\n'.join(str(permutation) for permutation in obj))
```

But again, simple `for` loop which you are using already is just fine. Remember that [simple is better than complex](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Thanks for your expanded answer, @Ernest!