# Python - How can I get a list of all the fields in my struct?

Tags: python, struct

I've found the below code to allow me to create a "Matlab-like" struct variable:

```
class vidOutClass:
        pass

    vidOut = vidOutClass()
    vidOut.numOfFrames = numOfFrames
    vidOut.frameWidth = frameWidth
    vidOut.frameHeight = frameHeight
```

Now, I have my struct vidOut with 3 fields inside: "numOfFrames" , "frameWidth" , "frameHeight"

Is there a way for me to retrieve all existing fields in a struct?

In MATLAB it would like this:

```
fieldnames(vidOut)
```

which would yield a cell with all the field names.

THANKS !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.__dict__` to return a dictionary with the variable names as the keys and the values as the...values.

If you want to ONLY get the values, you can say `.__dict__.values()`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, I don't think you're using Python classes correctly. You can achieve the equivalent of structs with a [dictionary](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/DataStructures_II_Dictionaries.html), whereas Python [class](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module4_OOP/ClassDefinition.html) is more intended to be used like an actual class, with instances and all.

```
vidOut = {}
vidOut["numOfFrames"] = numOfFrames
vidOut["frameWidth"] = frameWidth
vidOut["frameHeight"] = frameHeight

print(vidOut.keys())
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander Ding. I now understand that dictionary is best suited to resemble MATLAB's struct.
My only dismay is that with dictionary I can't use the auto-fill feature. I mean, if I have a dictionary with 100 keys. I've created it last year, and I don't fully remember the exact names... now I'd like to find a key that related to "frames"...
Can I type some like: 'vidOut.fr' and it show me all the keys that start with letters 'fr' ?
Is there some workaround?

Comment: @MarkGolberg I think there are some efforts from Python to approximate C-like structs with more native support. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426493/7718577.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided might work but it is not the best practice, in Python you may use a class `constructor` function called `__init__` as follows:

```
class VidOutClass:
    def __init__(self, num_of_frames, frame_width, frame_height):
        self.num_of_frames = num_of_frames
        self.frame_width = frame_width
        self.frame_height = frame_height
```

Then call it like this:

```
# Will create a VidOutClass object with 10 frames, and width x height of 150x150
vid_out = VidOutClass(num_of_Frames=10, frame_width=150, frame_height=150)
```

And then as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109106/3376059) by @cnu you may use `__dict__.keys()`, or in your code:

```
for key, val in vid_out.__dict__.items():
    print(key, val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataclass.
Here is an example

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class VidOutClass:
    numOfFrames: int = 0
    frameWidth: int = 5


vidOutClass = VidOutClass()
print(vidOutClass.__annotations__)
```

output - a dict where the key is the field name and the value is the field type

```
{'numOfFrames': <class 'int'>, 'frameWidth': <class 'int'>}
```